# Maximum product of 13 adjacent digits - Project Euler

Tags: c++

Here's the 8th problem:

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

And I wrote the following code trying to solve it

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string number = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int i, selected[13], product = 1, temp, j, k = -1;

    do {
        k++;
        j = k;
        temp = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++, j++)
        {
            selected[i] = number[j];
        }

        for (int l = 0; l < 13; l++)
            temp *= selected[l];
        if (temp >= product)
            product = temp;
    } while (k <= 987);

    cout << "Maximum Product = " << product << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

But this produces some very big number as the product, and I can't seem to figure out the mistake in this.

Comment: You should skip over any sequence that has a 0 in it instead of multiplying.  You should be searching for the sequences that do not contain any 0's in them, not naively multiply anything you find.

Comment: Adding `if ( std::any_of(selected, selected + 13, [] (int n) { return n == 0; })` and if this is `true`, don't multiply and skip to the last non-zero digit and get the next 13.  Otherwise you're just multiplying one-by-one -- these Euler and other coding sites have time-out settings, and your solution (once you correct the ASCII issue) may time-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're acting like each character is the number it looks like.  But ASCII `0` is not int `0`.

You might want something like this:

```
selected[i] = number[j] - '0'; /* convert ASCII to int */
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem apart from this was that I had made product and temp of type int. The product is much larger, so I now changed it to _int64 and it gives the right answer.